# css3 animations, fade-in as move-down?

Tags: css, animation, fadein, move

I am learning how to do css3 animations. How could I make this box fade in as it is moving down?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RtWTN/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 3s ease-out forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes mymove
{ 
  from { top: 0px;}
  to { top: 200px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add multiple rules to the animation keyframes.

```
{
from {top:0px; opacity: 0;}
to {top:200px; opacity: 1;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T2DnG/1/

Comment: Thankyou, how do i keep the box at the bottom after the animation, instead of it jumping back to the top?

Comment: @Ned `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

Answer (score 3):

Animating the *top* property is bad for browser performance. Just use `transform: translateY(<value>)`, this solution is by far more performant.

```
@keyframes mymove
{
  from {transform: translateY(0); opacity: 0;}
  to { transform: translateY(200px); opacity: 1;}
}
```

[Browsers are optimized for transforms and opacity](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/animations/animations-and-performance)